# Graph beta Teams Channels filesFolder property problem

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

There seems to be a number of issues with the "filesFolder" endpoint and the results are intermittent.

Using Graph to create channels (both private and standard) I then have these errors:

For newly created "private" channels it returns code: "BadGateway" errors. I don't know if they ever go away. The private channel site is created in Sharepoint. The error message: "Failed to execute backend request."

For newly created "standard" channels it always returns code: "NotFound" errors. I can find the channel folder in Sharepoint so I know it exists. The error message: "Sharepoint folder not found."

Comment: The files folder is not guaranteed to be available until someone actually views it - if you open the files tab on the team in question in Teams before calling the endpoint are you still receiving errors?

Comment: That may be fine from the UI but since I am doing everything from Graph, I need to something that will do this so I can put content into the DriveItem folder that is associated with the Private Channel.

Comment: We have created a bug for this issue and tracking it internally.

Comment: If you added a POST method for the filesFolder that would instantiate the SharePoint resources and Files then it could be done as needed.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT any update about this bug?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT any public info about this bug? Can't find any

Comment: Currently this is in our backlog. And there is not ETA on this.

Comment: Stewart, any workaround you could apply?

Comment: This is no programmatic solution to this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Really need this!
The older workaround to just create folders for the Channel using the same name and dummy files and then removing them --> links the SharePoint folder to the Channel when someone clicks the Files Tab for the first or second (because of random "cannot get files notification") time.

However --> we just want to provision nice short namings for the SharePoint folder for automation purposes and ALSO let users rename the channel if desired. So if someone renames the channel before they click on the Files tab --> the provisioned Folder never will be linked to a channel because Teams creates a new one with the renamed channel name

Comment: Your reply doesn't seems to be a solution but more as a reinforcement comment. Please be aware that this is not a chat room and your answer must addresses the problem's solution. There is a section for comments below each question where you can post your remarks.

Comment: Apologies!
Seems to be a UI / UX, I am not used to...

Comment: Please vote: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/41743294-default-files-tab-of-channel-programmatically-pro